# async scope is not working in Clustering in mule 3.4.2

Tags: mule, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

async scope is not working in Clustering in mule 3.4.2. we are getting below exception.

```
Message               : Interrupted while queueing event for "SEDA Stage Main_Flow.async1". Message payload is of type: ConfirmReceiveMessageResponse
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. com.sample.client.ReceiveMessageResponse (java.io.NotSerializableException)
  java.io.ObjectOutputStream:1183 (null)
2. java.io.NotSerializableException: com.elexon.bmrs.ecp.client.ReceiveMessageResponse (org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationException)
  org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils:111 (null)
3. Interrupted while queueing event for "SEDA Stage Main_Flow.async1". Message payload is of type: ConfirmReceiveMessageResponse (org.mule.api.service.FailedToQueueEventException)
  org.mule.processor.SedaStageInterceptingMessageProcessor:92 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/service/FailedToQueueEventException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.sample.client.ReceiveMessageResponse
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1183)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.commons.collections.map.AbstractHashedMap.doWriteObject(AbstractHashedMap.java:1182)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

After removing the async scope we are able to test the application. Could please help us how to make the application works with async in cluster env?

Comment: Are you using the Community version or the Enterprise version  ?

Comment: Mule EE 3.4.2 with Clustering agent .could please help us out?

Comment: Can you post your config? Are you using a flow-ref in you async block by any chance?

Comment: Yes!!! we are using flow-ref inside async scope. can't we use?

Answer (score 0):

If the flow ref is using an async processing strategy it will try and persist the event in a cluster I believe. And your object is not Serializable.

You can make `com.sample.client.ReceiveMessageResponse` implement `java.io.Serializable` if you want the message to be persisted.

Or you can try forcing the flow that you are flow-ref'ing  `processingStrategy="synchronous"` maybe.

Comment: where message will be persisted whether it will be persisted in java heap area (or) physical VM(filesystem) (or) anywhere else? .